# getting installation 16.04 LTS DVD

Tags: boot, live-cd

The instructions make installing from a DVD look easiest.  How do I get the DVD?  I just made the $15 donation.

A couple days ago, a popup offered to upgrade my Ubuntu to 16.04.  I went with it and now have bootup problems.  A reinstallation might solve the problem.  What do you think?

Comment: Do you wanto to purge your current ubuntu 16.04 and install it again from DVD? If yes, I yould recommend you to use a bootable pen drive. There are many videos os youtube showing how to do so. One is "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ubuntu+16.04+installation"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Canonical sells DVDs anymore (just USB drives with 16.04 pre-loaded onto them). You can buy an Ubuntu USB drive at http://shop.ubuntu.com

If you prefer a DVD, there are many to choose from on eBay for around $5 or less. Search eBay for "Ubuntu 16.04 DVD" and you'll find lots of them. Alternatively, ask your tech-savvy nephew, friend, or coworker to burn one for you.